# How do I get month names from this Linq group by query?

Tags: c#, linq

I use this query in LINQ to get grouped data:

```
string fmt = "yyyyMM";
var pivotedMeanResults =
    meanDataResults
    .GroupBy(i => i.Description)
    .Select(g => new PivotedMeanData
    {
        Description = g.Key,
        Month3Value = g.Where(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.CollectionPeriod, fmt, invariantCulture).Month == currentMonth - 3).FirstOrDefault().LabResultNo.ToString(),
        Month2Value = g.Where(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.CollectionPeriod, fmt, invariantCulture).Month == currentMonth - 2).FirstOrDefault().LabResultNo.ToString(),
        Month1Value = g.Where(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.CollectionPeriod, fmt, invariantCulture).Month == currentMonth - 1).FirstOrDefault().LabResultNo.ToString()
        Month3Name = ? //
        Month2Name = ? //
        Month1Name = ? //
    }).ToList();
```

Data is in this format:

```
Item    Collection_Period   Value
====    =================   =====
Item4       201308          19
Item3       201209          2.1
Item2       201307          345
Item1       201309          13.11
Item2       201308          34
Item4       201308          58.2
Item3       201209          2.4
Item2       201309          12.1
Item1       201209          12.3
```

I need to manipulate data into this format, which, I am getting as needed:

```
Item    Month3Name  Month2Name  Month1Name
=====   =========   =========   =========
Item1                           13.11
Item2   345         34          12.1
Item3   
Item4   19          58.2
```

but I want to know if it is possible to get the month names (Month1Name, Month2Name, Month3Name) based on how the equivalent month values are derived in the grouping?

---

PS: I know I can generate month names can be generated like this:

```
CultureInfo cInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTimeFormatInfo english = cInfo.DateTimeFormat;
english.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(integer)
```

So I tried this

```
Month3Name = english.GetAbbreviatedMonthName
(g.Where(DateTime.ParseExact(c.CollectionPeriod, fmt, invariantCulture)
.Month == currentMonth - 3))
```

but I get the errors:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`<Namespace.Type.MeanData>`' to 'int'
>
> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: One comment: it looks like you're subtracting one, two, and three from the month numbers in order to refer to previous months. Remember that this won't work before April 1 of each year.

Comment: @Tenner: I am sorry I am so dense right now, can you please explain why it is so?

Comment: @A: April=4;   March=3;  so April - 3 = 1 (January). But March - 3 = 0! (I am not sure, if this is of concern for your particular query.)

Comment: Ok, that's just plain stupid of me. I will use one of the DateTime methods for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the name of the current month -1, -2, -3.

Then why are you trying tho get the name of the month from a subset of your data??

```
Month3Name = english.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(currentMonth - 3)
```

seems a lot more likely to give yo a monthname?

And yes, you cannot subtract 2 from January and expect a valid month :)

Answer (score 0):

Just format dates like below; It will return the month name of the date.

```
        string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
        //or
        month = new DateTime(1, 3, 1).ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```